# Can I release dev and stable versions together

Tags: python, pip, python-packaging

Let's say I have a stable `0.8.4` version of my package. Let's also say I released a `1.0.0.dev1` version in a separate branch.

Can I still release versions e.g. `0.8.5` or `0.9.0` while I am developing my `1.0.0` version?

Comment: Packages release security patches all the time

Comment: @Sayse, what does it mean?

Comment: Take django for example, [they'll release multiple versions practically every time](https://www.djangoproject.com/weblog/2024/jan/02/bugfix-release/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

The default behaviour of pip (also pipenv/poetry) is to ignore pre-release versions (eg dev, alpha) in favour of the latest stable version.

This is a common pattern for pre-releasing features that may not yet be fully tested or stable while continuing to maintain the latest stable release.